# Resize container resources online

Tags: resources, docker

How can I resize container resources after creation, when it is online? I would like to get a permanent solution for this, that isn't reset when restarting.
I've set resources in creation time with following options:

```
-c, --cpu-shares=0  
--cpuset=""  
-m, --memory=""
```

I have already tried to change values here

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/
```

Comment: what was the downvote for? if it was OT, why not flag it so?

Comment: don´t understand the downvote. I did an upvote, it´s interesting an cgroups are the right place to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box you can't do this, containers are meant to be immutable at least configuration wise.

You might be better off using [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to define these parameters so they are always set for a given application.

An untested example `docker-compose.yml` might look like this :

```
awesome_app:
    cpu_shares: 0
    cpu_set: 0
    memory: 0
```

Comment: Yes, but `Compose` is suitable for multi container applications. First of all, I have created my image with use of `commit` from an existing container.

Comment: committing to build an image is fine for prototyping, but at some point you need to derive a final master image using Dockerfile. It's best practice and will avoid bloated images.

Comment: Standardization is great, but has much more consumption of time, that maybe isn't worth if we need only a "short living" container.

Comment: can you post how you generate these short lived containers? if you're creating them successively then, why not amend the values as and when you need them? what's the purpose of adjust the resources dynamically? i might be able to come up with an alternative answer.

Comment: I know the exact needs. After that I should configure this in a container, make image from it and replicate it(for some departments). The most important thing is, that these containers should be with same configuration, but if a department has different memory amount request, it should be increased on the fly, quickly.